# Display data on html using jquery loadJSON function

Tags: jquery, html

I need to display data on html using jquery loadJSON function or through some other way. My html is being created by designer which will have placeholder for all the fields(30-40 fields), i just need to populate those with my json response data.
I am getting json response data successfully. For sample, i have just hard coded the data below.

But i am getting below error -

```
TypeError: $(...).loadJSON is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$('div#data222222').loadJSON(data);


JS - loads the data
function getEmployeeList() {
    $.getJSON("http://l0.1.2.3:8080/jQueryJAXRS/rest/employees", function(data) {
          data = {
                  "Name":"Emkay Entertainments",
                  "Address":"Nobel House, Regent Centre",
                  "Contact":"Phone"
      }  ;

          $('#data').loadJSON(data);
    });
}   


HTML -  data to display

    <div id="data">
            <h1 id="Name"></h1>
            <label for="Address">Address:</label>
            <span id="Address"></span>  
            <label for="Contact">Contact by:</label>
            <span id="Contact"></span>
        </div>


Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Error is 

$('#data').loadJSON(data);

Comment: There is no .loadJSON function in the native jQuery library. You're trying to do data binding - might be better off with something like Angular.

Comment: Are you including the loadJSON plugin on the page?

Comment: @Gaurav can you solve this problem?

Comment: if yousolve this than please post a answer that will help me and others